# Call a controller function from directive with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can a directive call a function from a controller with some parameters ?

I would to give the variable myVar to the scope.$apply(attrs.whattodo);

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="component">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span ng-repeat="i in myarray">
     <span  customattr  whattodo="addVal">{{i}}</span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Controller JS :

```
   function ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.myarray = [1];
      $scope.addVal = function (value) {
          $scope.myarray.push(value);
      }
   }
```

Directive JS :

```
angular.module('component', []).directive('customattr', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var myVar = 5;
          scope.$apply(attrs.whattodo);
      } 
  }; 
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is one of the working methods:

You have to bind this attribute in scope as a scope model with function type. So you can execute this when you need in other (directive) sope

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Value: {{value}}!

  <button customattr whattodo="addValue">Add</button>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('component', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 1;

  $scope.addValue = function(val){
    alert(val);
    $scope.value = val;
  }
});

.directive('customattr', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          whattodo: "=" // or ' someOtherScopeName: "=whattodo" '
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var myVar = 5;
          scope.whattodo(myVar); // or ' scope.someOtherScopeName(myVar) '
      } 
  }; 
});
```

Here is **[code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QdwMf9jDXz7ClYm77r8H)**

> **from** [AngularJS: Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>   name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will
>   reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to
>   parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in
>   localModel will reflect in parentModel

Comment: That works great thanks. One last thing : the example I gave was a dumy one. But with my "real" example : the value is an list of dicts that I render with some input text. If I put the empty scope or the scope you gave, all my input fields become empty. Any idea why ? Thank you

Comment: Honestly difficult to imagine it, wouldn't be complicated for you to move your real eample into plunker? Thanks

Comment: Of course ! Here it is : http://plnkr.co/edit/mu9DM1dEyZ36UqVvw0DM
Just put the scope to true in the directive and you will see "Toto" in it. Or

Comment: Yeah, now I see.. It's because you isolated scope of this element by adding it in directive. So you just need to address to $parent now. (ng-model="$parent.value.name") see it here  http://plnkr.co/edit/IHqq88Gix26psfUeEhcS?p=preview

Comment: @JohnCastle, plese let me know does it work for you ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

in html

```
whattodo="addVal(value)"
```

in directive

```
scope.$apply(function(s){
    s.whattodo({value : myVar});
});
```

Comment: I got : TypeError: Property 'whattodo' of object #<Object> is not a function?

Comment: Very interesting, and works well ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/rhXDs/)). After some thought, the same thing must be used in things like `<button ng-click="myFunc($event)">`. As long as the API user uses the right variable name, you can set any locals as necessary.

Comment: What is the 's'? Is that the scope?

Comment: Yes it is short form :)

Comment: I just want to add that naming the variable when calling from the directive is essential. Otherwise the passed variables will be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the "&" sign in isolated scope?

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Value: {{value}}!
  <button customattr add-val="addValue(value)">Add</button>
</body>
```

In controller:

```
   function ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.myarray = [1];
      $scope.addValue = function (value) {
          $scope.myarray.push(value);
      }
   }
```

And in directive:

```
angular.module('component', []).directive('customattr', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          addVal: "&"
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
          var myVar = 5;
             // To execute addVal in controller with 'value' param
          $scope.addVal({value: value}) 
      } 
  }; 
});
```

Comment: in directive where ever you have used addVal ,use whattodo instead